# alternatives --config java gives an error

Tags: java, fedora

I recently had Fedora 12, but have upgraded to Fedora 14 using the preupgrade command-line tool.

Since I upgraded I've been having a few problems, and one is that the command
alternatives --config java
no longer works. Instead of giving me a list of JREs to choose from (I had 3 before the upgrade), it says this

> failed to read link /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

I don't understand enough about how alternatives works, or how Linux works, to know what to do about this. Can anyone help?

Thanks
Neil

Comment: Where do that link and `/etc/alternatives/java` currently point?